# sql query comparing values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

It's a SQL question I found when I'm preparing the interview.

how can you efficiently find all those records whose value is bigger than the previous one's?

```
ID      1   2   3    4   5   

value   6   5   10   8   30
```

Comment: Can you tell us the expected output and what you have tried?

Comment: use a self join with two join conditions.

Comment: Is the data in one row, two rows, or are there two columns per row?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a self join for this. As long as the question is definitely to compare only the current record to the previous record (and not all previous records).

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2
        ON t1.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE   
    t1.value > t2.value
```

Comment: You should add a caveat that this only works if there are no gaps in the ID sequence.

Comment: And that ID is truly a UPI*

Comment: Is your comparison operator backwards?

Comment: @Mackers Yea... My heart wasn't in it. Fixed though :)

Answer (score 0):

JNevill's answer works if IDs are sequential, with no gaps. If there can be missing IDs, this may work better:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, value > @prevValue AS greater, @prevValue := value
    FROM (SELECT *
          FROM YourTable
          ORDER BY id) AS t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevValue := null) AS init) AS t1
WHERE greater = 1
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ae0f/2)